# Jquery Data Tables Can't post data with Ajax (asp.Net)

Tags: ajax, datatables, asp.net-ajax

I've been trying to post data to jquery Data Tables but i couldn't. I have a web method in server side which returns data as object array. I need to get data with ajax post. But i can't. So i need some help.

Here is my c# web method:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static object[] Questions()
    {
        table = new DataTable();
        List<object> questionList = new List<object>();
        table = RunSelectCommand("SELECT QUESTION_ID,QUESTION_TEXT,QUESTION_GROUP FROM QUESTIONS WHERE QUESTION_ACTIVE='Y'");
        for(int i=0 ; i<table.Rows.Count ; i++)
        {
            questionList.Add(new
            {
                q_id = table.Rows[i]["QUESTION_ID"].ToString(),
                q_text = table.Rows[i]["QUESTION_TEXT"].ToString(),
                q_group = table.Rows[i]["QUESTION_GROUP"].ToString()
            });
        }

        return questionList.ToArray();
    }
```

And jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#questTable').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide:true,
            ajax: {
                url: 'Question.aspx/Questions',
                type:'POST'
            },
            columns: [
                { data: 'q_id' },
                { data: 'q_text' },
                { data: 'q_group' }
            ]
        });
    });
```

**But** i debuged it with break point and i noticed that **web method doesn't work.** And here is the error that i get: **DataTables warning: table id=questTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the [server-side documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side), particularly the section `Returned data`.

Comment: I've solved the problem, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was about my web method returns object array and data tables doesn't accept it. That's why i got **Invalid JSON response.** error. So i change my js structure. I post data as usual then i use data tables **data** property for post. It works:

```
function GetData()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'Question.aspx/Questions',
            data: '{}',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#questTable').DataTable({
                    data:result.d,
                    columns: [
                        { data: 'q_id' },
                        { data: 'q_text' },
                        { data: 'q_group' }
                    ]
                });}
     }
```